# Regex for query substring

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex (Python) that matches a specific query's substring until another substring occurs, if it does. In order to understand this better I provide a few examples:

```
# Query 1
title:chicago bullie
```

In each query, my goal is to capture the `title` and the string(s) that follow it. I started with the regex `title:.*` that captures the whole query `title:chicago bullie`. The queries become more complex, by including other elements:

```
# Query 2
title:chicago bullie author:adam
```

In this case, the query `title:.*` no longer works because my goal is to capture only `title:chicago bullie` and exclude the other element `author:adam`. In other words, I want to capture the `title` keyword, followed by a string or multiple strings until the query ends or another keyword occurs (e.g. author, year, etc.). Note that keywords are always followed by `:` and a string or multiple strings. Queries may also include the keyword `AND` to denote the last keyword:

```
# Query 3
title:chicago bullie AND author:adam
```

My thought was to use a negative lookahead to capture the substring `title:<string(s)>` until the string ends or another keyword (followed by `:` and other string(s)) occurs. I came up with the regex `title:.* (?!:)`, but I'm not sure this is the best way to accomplish this. It does work for all examples except for those with the `AND` keyword.

```
# Query 3
type:action title:chicago bullie one author:adam
Captured group: title:chicago bullie

# Query 4
type:action title:chicago bullie one AND author:adam
Captured group: title:chicago bullie AND
```

While the regex works for queries without `AND` keywords, I still think the solution is not perfect for those cases. Note that there's a whitespace character separating `title:.*` and the negative lookahead `(?!:)`.

Is there a clean(er) way to encompass all the requirements listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern with positive lookahead:

```
.*?(title:.*?)(?=AND|\w+:|$)
```

which when added to code looks like:

```
def find_match(query):
    return re.match(r'.*?(title:.*?)(?=AND|\w+:|$)', query).group(1).strip()
```

and when run:

```
>>> find_match('title:chicago bullie')
title:chicago bullie
>>> find_match('title:chicago bullie author:adam')
title:chicago bullie
>>> find_match('title:chicago bullie AND author:adam')
title:chicago bullie
```

Comment: `author` was just an example of a keyword, there are several others that may be considered. In this task, it is enough to just consider a keyword ANY word that is followed by `:`. In that case `author` should be replaced by any word.

Comment: @Khabz, my misunderstanding. Updated.

Comment: Note that this matches an extra space, and that it only matches `title` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @blhsing, should fix that now.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
import re

PATT = r'.*?(title:.*?)(\w+:|AND|$)'
MYRE = re.compile(PATT, re.M)
ans = MYRE.findall(c)
ans = [x[0] for x in ans]
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern with alternation between a word followed by a colon and optionally preceded by `AND`, and the end of the string:

```
re.search(r'\btitle:.*?(?=\s*(?:AND\s+)?\w+:|$)', s).group()
```

so that given `s = 'type:action title:chicago bullie one AND author:adam'`, this returns:

```
title:chicago bullie one
```